# How can i share data/text with other apps that will accept it?

Tags: android

I have an app that creates a new data entry in a sqlite db with several columns. I would like to have a simple *share* button on the final activity so they can share the results (or even a simple text field) with apps that accept it (email, mms, twitter, etc..).

I did some reading on ContentProviders but the more I read, the more I'm thinking i'm heading down the wrong path. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).  Android applications have two major components: Activities and Intents.  Activities are processes that do a particular action, like a ListView, or a process that sets and listens in the background for something to happen.  An Intent is a message between those actions.  It's how processes communicate in Android.  Intents can be specific, and tell a particular Activity to perform an action on some data, OR you it can attempt to perform some action (like open in browser) by any available "browser" application that can perform that action.

Here are some links to the documentation to get you started:

[android.content.Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Intents and Intent Resolution](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tie the app to a web service and put the data up in the cloud.